# Spinner con un texto inicial

Tags: android, arraylist, spinner, adapter

Cordial saludo, mediante una consulta a una página:

```
http://localhost/baradm/ubica.php?id=002
```

obtengo la respuesta .json:

```
[{"DESCRP":"MESA 01"},{"DESCRP":"CUARTO 01"},{"DESCRP":"CUARTO 02"}]
```

Esto lo he cargado a un Spinner:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Y deseo que el texto UBICACION... me aparezca como texto incial y que este no sea seleccionable, he ubicado una ayuda en este [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/867518/how-to-make-an-android-spinner-with-initial-text-select-one), pero no se como implementarlo, adjunto las clases java con las que lleno el spinner.

Gracias de antemano.

**PEDIDOFRAGMENT.JAVA**

```
package com.windroid.dinas;

import...;


public class PedidoFragment extends Fragment{

    final static String urlAddress="http://10.0.3.2/baradm/ubica.php?id=";

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // Inflate the layout for this fragment
        View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_pedido, container, false);
        final Spinner spinnerUbica = (Spinner) view.findViewById(R.id.spUbica);

        new Downloader(getActivity(),urlAddress+GlobalVariables.getUsr(),spinnerUbica).execute();

        return view;
    }

}
```

**DOWNLOADER.JAVA**

```
package com.windroid.dinas;

import...

public class Downloader extends AsyncTask<Void,Void,String> {

    Context c;
    String urlAddress;
    Spinner sp;

    ProgressDialog pd;


    public Downloader(Context c, String urlAddress, Spinner sp) {
        this.c = c;
        this.urlAddress = urlAddress;
        this.sp = sp;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {
        super.onPreExecute();

        pd=new ProgressDialog(c);
        pd.setTitle("Buscando");
        pd.setMessage("Buscando...Por favor, espere");
        pd.show();
    }

    @Override
    protected String doInBackground(Void... params) {
        return this.downloadData();
    }


    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(String s) {
        super.onPostExecute(s);

        pd.dismiss();

        if(s==null)
        {
            Toast.makeText(c,"No se puede recuperar, valor nulo devuelto",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }else
        {
            Toast.makeText(c,"Exito",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

            //CALL PARSER CLASS TO PARSE
             DataParser parser=new DataParser(c,sp,s);
            parser.execute();
        }
    }

    private String downloadData()
    {
        HttpURLConnection con=Connector.connect(urlAddress);
        if(con==null)
        {
            return null;
        }

        InputStream is=null;
        try {

            is=new BufferedInputStream(con.getInputStream());
            BufferedReader br=new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(is));

            String line=null;
            StringBuffer response=new StringBuffer();

            if(br != null)
            {
                while ((line=br.readLine()) != null)
                {
                    response.append(line+"\n");
                }

                br.close();

            }else {
                return null;
            }

            return response.toString();

        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }finally {
            if(is != null)
            {
                try {
                    is.close();
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        }
        return null;
    }
}
```

**DATAPARSER.JAVA**

```
package com.windroid.dinas;

import...


public class DataParser extends AsyncTask<Void,Void,Integer> {

    Context c;
    Spinner sp;
    String jsonData;

    ProgressDialog pd;
    ArrayList<String> spacecrafts=new ArrayList<>();

    public DataParser(Context c, Spinner sp, String jsonData) {
        this.c = c;
        this.sp = sp;
        this.jsonData = jsonData;
    }


    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {
        super.onPreExecute();


        pd=new ProgressDialog(c);
        pd.setTitle("Buscando");
        pd.setMessage("Buscando...Por favor, espere");
        pd.show();
    }

    @Override
    protected Integer doInBackground(Void... params) {
        return this.parseData();
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(Integer result) {
        super.onPostExecute(result);

        pd.dismiss();

        if(result==0)
        {
            Toast.makeText(c,"No se puede analizar",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }else
        {
            //Toast.makeText(c,"Analizado con Exito",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

            //BIND
            ArrayAdapter adapter=new ArrayAdapter(c,android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item,spacecrafts);

            adapter.add("UBICACION...");
            sp.setAdapter(adapter);


            sp.setOnItemSelectedListener(new AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener() {

                @Override
                public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {

                    Toast.makeText(c,spacecrafts.get(position),Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }

                @Override
                public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> parent) {

                }
            });

        }
    }

    private int parseData()
    {
        try {
            JSONArray ja=new JSONArray(jsonData);
            JSONObject jo=null;

            spacecrafts.clear();
            Spacecraft s=null;

            for(int i=0;i<ja.length();i++)
            {
                jo=ja.getJSONObject(i);

                //int id=jo.getInt("id");
                String name=jo.getString("DESCRP");

                s=new Spacecraft();
                //s.setId(id);
                s.setName(name);

                spacecrafts.add(name);
            }

            return 1;

        } catch (JSONException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        return 0;

    }

}
```

**ESPACECRAFT.JAVA**

```
package com.windroid.dinas.mDataObject;

public class Spacecraft {

    String name;

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }
}
```

Comment: Prueba esta solución, a mi me funciona. http://stackoverflow.com/a/14640612/5675636

Answer (score 1):

Los datos mostrados en el adapter se configuran mediante el `ArrayList<String> spacecrafts`, por lo tanto `"UBICACION..."` se encuentra como último elemento :

```
ArrayAdapter adapter=new ArrayAdapter(c,android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item,spacecrafts);
```

Las opciones son:

seleccionar el elemento del indice deseado, en este caso 3 por medio del método [**setSelection()**](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/AbsSpinner.html#setSelection(int,%20boolean)):

```
spinnerUbica.setSelection(3);
```

si deseas ir al primer elemento usa:

```
spinnerUbica.setSelection(0);
```

o también si deseas una animación:

```
spinnerUbica.setSelection(0, true);
```

> [**setSelection()**](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/AbsSpinner.html#setSelection(int,%20boolean)): Salta directamente a un elemento específico de
>   los datos del adaptador.

o asegurar que se inserte como primer elemento ya que si revisas en `onPostExectute()` de tu `AsyncTask` DataParser, se esta agregando posteriormente a tu `Spinner`, por esta razón se muestra al final del listado.

```
...
...
     //BIND
     ArrayAdapter adapter=new ArrayAdapter(c,android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item,spacecrafts);

     adapter.add("UBICACION...");
     sp.setAdapter(adapter);
...
...
```

Esto lo puedes realizar agregando el elemento deseado en el ArrayList antes de construir el spinner:

```
...
...

     spacecrafts.add(0, "UBICACION..."); //* Agrega como primer elemento del List.
     //BIND
     ArrayAdapter adapter=new ArrayAdapter(c,android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item,spacecrafts);

     //adapter.add("UBICACION...");
     sp.setAdapter(adapter);
...
...
```

esta segunda opción considero sería la adecuada para mostrar los datos correctamente en el `spinner`:

```
UBICACION...
MESA 01
CUARTO 01
CUARTO 02
```

Comment: Gracias por la respuesta, pero ya he logrado que quede como primera seleccion asi este de ultimo, lo que no se es que quede como titulo y no aparezca dentro de los items a seleccionar por el usuario, asi: http://es.tinypic.com/r/28cggfa/9