# Llenar un Spinner dependiente desde un Web Service

Tags: android, android-studio, webservice

esta es la primer pregunta que hago acá, espero hacerla correctamente.
Tengo una aplicación en Android y quiero llenar un Spinner dependiente mediante un Web Service, estoy utilizando LOOPJ.

El primer spinner ya lo he llenado correctamente, pero solo es un select * from a una tabla, al seleccionar una opción me manda a una segunda actividad que depende de la opción seleccionada, recupero el id de esa tabla y me debe llenar el segundo Spinner mediante una consulta con where, pero no me lo llena, no me muestra ningún error solamente aparece vacío.

El servicio Web lo he creado en c# y es un json que al probarlo en postman me devuelve correctamente el arreglo con los datos

```
String url = "http://examenrestwebapi251955201320190401082959.azurewebsites.net/api/Causas?idProblema=3";// no es mi examen xD solo tomé este proyecto ya subido para crear ahi el WS
```

Acá tengo los métodos correspondientes para la carga de datos y el llenando del Spinner

```
private void llenarSpiner(){ //este metodo lo cargo en el OnCreate
    Bundle datos = getIntent().getExtras();
    Integer id = datos.getInt("id");

    String url = "http://examenrestwebapi251955201320190401082959.azurewebsites.net/api/Causas?idProblema="+id;
    cliente.post(url, new AsyncHttpResponseHandler() {
        @Override
        public void onSuccess(int statusCode, Header[] headers, byte[] responseBody) {
            if(statusCode == 200){
                cargarSpinner(new String(responseBody));
            }
        }
        @Override
        public void onFailure(int statusCode, Header[] headers, byte[] responseBody, Throwable error) {
        }
    });
}

private void cargarSpinner(String respuesta){
    final ArrayList<Causas> lista = new ArrayList<Causas>();
    try{
        JSONArray jsonArreglo = new JSONArray(respuesta);
        for (int i=0; i<jsonArreglo.length(); i++){
            Causas p = new Causas();
            p.setID_CAUSAS(jsonArreglo.getJSONObject(i).getInt("ID_CAUSAS"));
            p.setDESCRIPCION_CAUSAS(jsonArreglo.getJSONObject(i).getString("DESCRIPCION_CAUSAS"));
            p.setID_PROBLEMA(jsonArreglo.getJSONObject(i).getInt("ID_PROBLEMA"));
            lista.add(p);
        }
        ArrayAdapter<Causas> a = new ArrayAdapter<Causas>(this,android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item,lista);
        spCausas.setAdapter(a);
    }
    catch (Exception e){
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

Esperando puedan solventar este inconveniente de que me sale en blanco el Spinner, muchas gracias.

Comment: podrias poner un else despues del statusCode ==200 para ver si ingresa al if

Comment: Hola, creo que no queda muy claro el problema, ¿el servicio si te regresa los datos invocandolo desde tu método ? ¿y el problema es que no pinta esos datos? o NO sabes si el servicio te trae los datos invocandolo desde tu método?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Si no te muestra datos es simplemente porque el adapter no esta recibiendo una lista de objetos `Causas` esto mediante la variable `lista` :

```
 ArrayAdapter<Causas> a = new ArrayAdapter<Causas>(this,android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item,lista);
```

---

Al realizar tu petición POST se obtiene:

```
{
    "Table": [{
        "ID_CAUSAS": 1,
        "DESCRIPCION_CAUSAS": "Arranque dañado",
        "ID_PROBLEMA": 3
    }, {
        "ID_CAUSAS": 2,
        "DESCRIPCION_CAUSAS": "Alternador dañado",
        "ID_PROBLEMA": 3
    }]
}
```

El problema en realidad es el parser, primeramente tratas de obtener el `JSONArray` 
 lo cual es incorrecto ya que tu respuesta obtiene un `JSONObject` que dentro contiene un `JSONArray` llamado "Table" , revisa:

[ERROR: org.json.JSONException: Value .... of type java.lang.String cannot be converted to JSONArray](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/35655/error-org-json-jsonexception-value-of-type-java-lang-string-cannot-be-con/35720#35720)

De acuerdo a la estructura, primero obtén el objeto y posteriormente el `JSONArray` "Table", para posteriormente iterar sobre los objetos de este array.

```
   ...
   ...
   try{
        //Obtiene objeto.
        JSONObject jsonRespuesta = new JSONObject(respuesta);
        //Obtiene array Table.
        JSONArray jsonArreglo = jsonRespuesta.getJSONArray("Table");
        //JSONArray jsonArreglo = new JSONArray(respuesta);
        //Itera sobre objetos contenidos en el Array Table.
        for (int i=0; i<jsonArreglo.length(); i++){
            Causas p = new Causas();
            p.setID_CAUSAS(jsonArreglo.getJSONObject(i).getInt("ID_CAUSAS"));
            p.setDESCRIPCION_CAUSAS(jsonArreglo.getJSONObject(i).getString("DESCRIPCION_CAUSAS"));
            p.setID_PROBLEMA(jsonArreglo.getJSONObject(i).getInt("ID_PROBLEMA"));
            lista.add(p);
        }
        ArrayAdapter<Causas> a = new ArrayAdapter<Causas>(this,android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item,lista);
        spCausas.setAdapter(a);
    }
    ...
    ...
```

Comment: Amigo muchas gracias, me ha servido de gran manera tu ayuda, ya lo pude solucionar el problema, enserio te lo agradezco

Comment: Me da mucho gusto @HERNÁNDEZEDSON , saludos!

Comment: Amigo tengo una duda mas como podría a ese segundo spinner poner en la posicion incial "seleccionar un valor" en base a ese mismo codigo?

Comment: Puedes usar spinner.setSelection(0,true); o spinner.setSelection(0); para posicionarte en el primer elemento (indice 0)  , revisa: https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/56004/spinner-con-un-texto-inicial/56065#56065